# Hibernate fails to persist even when cascade is ALL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities `AuthorizationPosition` and `ProductAttributes` in a `Wildfly` EE project. The mapping between the two is the following:

**AuthorizationPosition:**

```
  @javax.persistence.ManyToOne(fetch =  javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY , optional=false, cascade = {javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL})
  @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID", referencedColumnName="PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID")
  protected org.example.persistence.entity.ProductAttributes productAttributes;
```

**ProductAttributes:**

```
  @javax.persistence.OneToMany(
        targetEntity=org.example.persistence.entity.AuthorizationPosition.class,
        mappedBy="productAttributes",
        fetch=javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY
                    , cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL
                 , orphanRemoval = true         )
  protected java.util.Set<org.example.persistence.entity.AuthorizationPosition> authorizationPositionsByProductAttributes;
```

I set all the relation in both of the entities and call `em.persist()` on `ProductAttributes` (as part of a bigger structure) this is where the strange error appears (full stack trace at the end of the question):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : org.example.persistence.entity.AuthorizationPosition.productAttributes -> org.example.persistence.entity.ProductAttributes
```

Am I missing something or Hibernate (`hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final`) is really trying to persist in an other way around? Should not this be a problem though as `CascadeType.ALL` is present on all of the relation mappings?

**Full stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : org.example.persistence.entity.AuthorizationPosition.productAttributes -> org.example.persistence.entity.ProductAttributes
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:146) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:814) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:785) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.container.AbstractEntityManager.persist(AbstractEntityManager.java:580) [wildfly-jpa-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.example.control.ImportServoceImpl.import(ImportServoceImpl.java:109) [service-SNAPSHOT.jar:]
    at org.example.rest.control.ImportContainerService.importDocument(ImportContainerService.java:65) [classes:]
    at org.example.rest.control.ImportContainerService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.importDocument$$super(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceedInternal(TerminalAroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:51) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.AroundInvokeInvocationContext.proceed(AroundInvokeInvocationContext.java:78) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:79) [hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeAroundInvoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:84) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.executeInterception(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:72) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.InterceptorMethodHandler.invoke(InterceptorMethodHandler.java:56) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:79) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.invoke(CombinedInterceptorAndDecoratorStackMethodHandler.java:68) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.example.rest.control.ImportContainerService$Proxy$_$$_WeldSubclass.importDocument(Unknown Source) [classes:]
    at org.example.rest.boundary.ContainerRestService.import(ContainerRestService.java:181) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:92) [wildfly-weld-ejb-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.interceptorChainCompleted(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:107) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:126) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.cdi.internal.interceptor.ValidationInterceptor.validateMethodInvocation(ValidationInterceptor.java:79) [hibernate-validator-cdi-6.0.10.Final.jar:6.0.10.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) [rt.jar:1.8.0_191]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.reader.SimpleInterceptorInvocation$SimpleMethodInvocation.invoke(SimpleInterceptorInvocation.java:73) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.invokeNext(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:92) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.interceptor.proxy.WeldInvocationContextImpl.proceed(WeldInvocationContextImpl.java:124) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.InterceptorImpl.intercept(InterceptorImpl.java:105) [weld-core-impl-3.0.4.Final.jar:3.0.4.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.proceed(DelegatingInterceptorInvocationContext.java:82) [wildfly-weld-ejb-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.delegateInterception(EjbComponentInterceptorSupport.java:60)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.delegateInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43) [wildfly-ejb3-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47) [wildfly-jpa-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45) [wildfly-ee-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51) [wildfly-ejb3-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237) [wildfly-ejb3-13.0.0.Final.jar:13.0.0.Final]
    ... 104 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: Not-null property references a transient value - transient instance must be saved before current operation : org.example.persistence.entity.AuthorizationPosition.productAttributes -> org.example.persistence.entity.ProductAttributes
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(UnresolvedEntityInsertActions.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(ActionQueue.java:436) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkNoUnresolvedActionsAfterOperation(SessionImpl.java:648) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811) [hibernate-core-5.3.1.Final.jar:5.3.1.Final]
    ... 168 more
```

**Persistence unit properties:**

```
   <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.isolation" value="READ_COMMITTED"/>
        <property name="hibernate.listeners.envers.autoRegister" value="false"/>
        <!--<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers" value="true"/>-->
        <!-- note: no DDL validation, because it kicks in before Liquibase gets a chance to update the schema
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate"/>
        -->

        <!-- hibernate version integrated in Wildfly states:
        Legacy Hibernate behavior was to ignore the @DiscriminatorColumn.
        However, as part of issue HHH-6911 we now apply the explicit @DiscriminatorColumn.
        If you would prefer the legacy behavior, enable the `hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined`
        setting (hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined=true) -->
        <property name="hibernate.discriminator.ignore_explicit_for_joined" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableDirtyTracking" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableLazyInitialization" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.enhancer.enableAssociationManagement" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="${hibernate.showsql}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.use_sql_comments" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_structured_entries" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="64"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="100"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data" value="false"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true"/>

        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="false"/>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
    </properties>
```

***Edit1:***

I set the relation on both of the entities. I use similar code to the following (some parts are removed due to clarity):

```
public void addAuthorizationPositionByProductAttributes(@NotNull AuthorizationPosition authorizationPositionByProductAttributes) {
   if(this.authorizationPositionsByProductAttributes.add(authorizationPositionByProductAttributes)){
      authorizationPositionByProductAttributes.setProductAttributes(this);
   }
}
```

When I check it in debug, the values are set correctly.

Comment: can you show how you set-up entities before persist?

Comment: hi, maybe you could remove the Cascade.ALL from the ProductAttributes -> AuthorizationPosition link ? I am not sure if this would solve the issue, but I think this may cause the entity "ProductAttributes" to be persisted twice

Comment: I tried it.. The original state of mapping was without that :/

Comment: Remove , these configurations  orphanRemoval = true , referencedColumnName="PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID") optional=false,  and will work.

Comment: I tried this but it results in a nullconstraint validation error from the db `ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into...` Could you elaborate a bit more on why do you suspect these properties?

Comment: Can it be that same AuthorizationPosition entity is added to two ProductAttributes? Can I see where addAuthorizationPositionByProductAttributes is called?

Comment: @Mark please try to remove optional and add nullable=false to the join column and change lazy to Eager, and give us a feedback.

Comment: @alekz it cannot be added, it is basic call after creating a new element.

Comment: @TiMr tried with no luck.. Correct me if I am wrong but fetching should not play a role while presisting entities, right?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on entity with database table structure. Because this part is not working in my example @javax.persistence.JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID", referencedColumnName="PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID")

Comment: @alekz what do you mean by not working? The referenced column name equals with the name in the current name.

Comment: What am I missing? 
[link](https://github.com/oleksandrkovalenko/hibernate-test) Because this is working

Comment: @alekz there is a bug in hibernate validation... having the `<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>` set in persistence xml the behaviour is as expected.

Comment: @Mark: Does the `ProductAttributes` have an ID (assigned), when you `set` it (the association)?

Comment: @xerx593 No. Everything in the structure is new. When I call persist everything gets an `id` as expected, but the persist fails.

Comment: ..then problem/solution is clear: an entity *MUST* have an id, before it can be (persisted as) a "foreign key". ...`transient instance must be saved before current operation`

Comment: .....so please call `save()` (persist or merge...) on `ProductAttributes` , **before** you `addAuthorizationPositionByProductAttributes` ... on it. ..or `setProductAttributes` it.

Comment: @xerx593 This is what cascade should do. The question is why cascading does not work...

Comment: ....i got more confused after trying & reviewing @alekz' sample. works like charm...and even more confused, when adding more authorization positions (in same tx) - (other) exceptions get raised, connected to id, generation & transient state.

Comment: ..please provide us with "id" declarations (+annotations) of both entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am kind of surprised. We tried all of the suggestions:

- @mrtna `remove Cascade.ALL from the ProductAttributes -> AuthorizationPosition`
- @JonathanJohx `remove orphanRemoval = true , referencedColumnName="PRODUCT_ATTRIBUTES_ID") optional=false,`
- @TiMr `remove optional and add nullable=false to the join column and change lazy to Eager`
- @alekz `same AuthorizationPosition entity is added to two ProductAttributes?`

But nothing seemed to work some caused null constraint validation problems (`ORA-01400`) others were behaving exactly the same.

While testing performance we disabled validation completely (for a comparison test) in `persistence.xml`:

```
<validation-mode>NONE</validation-mode>
```

And with and accidental missclick on the wrong file to upload - to my surprise - the structure persisted fine without having any errors or constraint violations...

***TL.DR.:*** it is a hibernate bug in the validator which prevented us to persist. In case the `validation-mode` was set to `NONE` the structure got persisted. We check the validation information now previous to the `em.persist(..)` call and evaluate the results accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to remove `optional=false` from AuthorizationPosition?

Sometimes, Hibernate doesn't manage to put things in the "correct" order.

Hibernate sometimes needs to store NULL in foreign keys, even though there is a theoretical way to avoid it. You have to remove not-null constraints in these cases. (I removed all my not-null constraints from foreign keys ...)

You could try to remove the cascade from `AuthorizationPosition`, it might be the cause of the ordering problem. But I guess it wouldn't change anything.